# How to change input size in semantic ui?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I want to adjust width and height of input box in sementic ui but it is not working why so ?

code:

index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

login.js:

```
export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h5>Please login below</h5>
        <form className="ui form">
            <div className="field">
                <label>URN Number</label>
                <input className="fname" type="text" name="number" placeholder="Enter URN number"/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input className="pwd" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
            </div>
            <button className="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to reduce size of input box how can I do it ?

What I tried :

1)

```
form .fname {
        width: 60px;
    }
```

2)

```
.ui.input {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

3)

```
.fname {
width: 50px;
}
```

None of the above works why so ?

See screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After inspecting the code, the UI adds some styles to the inputs with this selector `.ui.form  input[type='text']` so use the same selector to override the styles. Or even more specific : `form.ui.form  input[type='text']` .

Most of the times with this kind of problems it's about the specificity of the css selector.

In your examples all are good except `.ui.input` which does not select anything. `.ui` is the class of the form, `.input` does not exist. I suggest you look up the css selectors. For example here -> [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Check snippet below or fiddle -> [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7s4kbje0/1/)

```css
form.ui.form  input[type='text'] {
  width:150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">

<div>
  <h5>Please login below</h5>
  <form class="ui form">
    <div class="field">
      <label>URN Number</label>
      <input class="fname" type="text" name="number" placeholder="Enter URN number" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input class="pwd" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" />
    </div>
    <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

P.S. in the future, create a working SO code snippet ( `<>` incon in the toolbar ) instead of just pasting some code. Event though it's JSX , it's easy to convert it in HTML.

Comment: I just want to ask whenever I have add custom css to semantic ui elements then I should always do `.ui.form{ my css } ` similarly for button `.ui.button { my css }` and for input `ui.form input { my css }` is it correct ?

Comment: First of all if you are not sure how the UI adds css. Inspect with developer tools ( right click -> inspect element in chrome )  and you can see the exact selector the UI is using. But yes, in general when you need to override some custom styles, you should use a much more specific selector. Like `form.ui.form element {}`.  Where `form` is the tag name and `.ui` and `.form` are the classes. This way, you are sure you override any custom css added by the UI

Comment: This code doesn't work -> `form.ui.button {
    border-radius: 10px;
}`why so ?

Comment: because `button` is not a class of the `form`. That's why i said you should read about CSS selectors. You can write `form.ui button {}` or `form .ui.button {}` or `form.ui.form button` or `form button.ui {}` etc. Many ways to write it. You just have to understand how you make the connection between elements and their classes and the order ( parent -> child )